# How to write regex for taking output from thrid line for this expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

```
Netvisor OS Command Line Interface 5.1
Connected to Switch ugui-9kleaf1; nvOS Identifier:0xb00163e; Ver: 5.1.0-5010014593
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.
CLI (network-admin@ugui-9kleaf1) > fabric-node-show format name no-show-headers
```

[image]

### name

```
ugui-9kleaf1
ugui-9kleaf2
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.
```

This is my expression

I have tried the below regex

```
r">.*[\r\n]?(.*)"
```

Output i am getting is

```
fabric-node-show format name, no-show-headers
ugui-9kleaf1
ugui-9kleaf2
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.
```

i want actual output.

```
ugui-9kleaf1
ugui-9kleaf2
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.
```

The above regex is capturing (command + output) but i need only actual output.

```
Netvisor OS Command Line Interface 5.1
Connected to Switch ugui-9kleaf1; nvOS Identifier:0xb00163e; Ver: 5.1.0-5010014593
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.
CLI (network-admin@ugui-9kleaf1) >
```

`>` symbol in my regex will skip the banner of my regex.

Command: fabric-node-show format name, no-show-headers
output what i am getting:
`fabric-node-show format name, no-show-headers
ugui-9kleaf1
ugui-9kleaf2
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.`

Output i want.

`ugui-9kleaf1
ugui-9kleaf2
Warning! ugui-9kleaf1's time is not in sync with the NTP Server.`

The above regex is capturing (command + output) but i need only actual output.

Note: Commands may change time to time so i can hardcode the value. so i want a generic regex where i captures only acutal output every time.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you need? Please properly format/ clarify your question.

Comment: @BlackPearl i have added image please have a look at it

Comment: I want test-fabric as my output. And no-show-headers is not constant every time it might change depending on requirement

Comment: I don't see `test-fabric` anywhere in your question, and it is still not clear. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the below regex
>
> ```
> r">.*[\r\n]?(.*)"
> ```

This is almost it. As we see in your image, match group 1 (green) contains the first line of the desired output, so we just have to extend match group 1 to the end. To do that, we can use the flag `s` (*dot matches newline*), but not for the whole regex (since it must not apply to the first `.`), only for group 1, so we have to use an *inline modifier* `(?s)`:

```
r">.*[\r\n]?((?s).*)"
```

[See online.](https://regex101.com/r/NkGvJa/1)